# Google Maps Lat/Long data from JSON not rendering

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps

I'm trying to draw some polygons onto Google Maps, using data pulled from a JSON request.  I can print out the coordinates or manually specify the coordinates just fine, but I can't draw the coordinates.  I'm trying to get a polygon, but I tried just drawing markers for the first coordinate for each polygon and wasn't able to get results that way either.  Here's the jQuery getJSON call:

```
    $.getJSON('getPolys', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, bound) {
            boundsCoords = [
                new google.maps.LatLng(bound.minLatitude, bound.minLongitude),
                new google.maps.LatLng(bound.minLatitude, bound.maxLongitude),
                new google.maps.LatLng(bound.maxLatitude, bound.maxLongitude),
                new google.maps.LatLng(bound.maxLatitude, bound.minLongitude),
                new google.maps.LatLng(bound.minLatitude, bound.minLongitude),
            ];
            boundsPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: boundsCoords,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.15
            });
            boundsPoly.setMap(map);
        });
    });
```

Also, an example of my json response:

```
[{"minLatitude":-79.458618,"minLongitude":43.645541,"maxLatitude":-79.431152,"maxLongitude":43.664129},{"minLatitude":-79.431152,"minLongitude":43.645541,"maxLatitude":-79.403687,"maxLongitude":43.664129},{"minLatitude":-79.403687,"minLongitude":43.645541,"maxLatitude":-79.376221,"maxLongitude":43.664129}]
```

If instead of populating boundsCoords from the json results I type in the coordinates, the poly renders just fine.

Comment: My fault... I had my lat and long flipped in my json.  Everything was rendering on the south pole.

Answer (score 0):

My fault... I had my lat and long flipped in my json. Everything was rendering on the south pole.